# reading a file from current directory in java

Tags: java, file

I have a java project where I am reading a file. As the file is in the current directory I am doing this:

```
String dataset = "./myFile.dat";
```

But I am getting: `java.io.FileNotFoundException` saying It can not find the file.

How to fix this?  When I give entire path it works...

```
String dataset = "C:\\eclipse\\workspace\\p1\\src\\myFile.dat";
```

Comment: What happens if you prepend `System.getProperty("user.dir")`?

Comment: maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480398/java-reading-a-file-from-current-directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `myFile.dat` is an application resource, it should be included in a Jar that is on the run-time class-path of the application.  Then an URL to the resource can be formed using..

```
URL urlToData = this.getClass().getResource("path/in/jar/to/myFile.dat");
```

**Don't** rely on the `user.dir` property.  Depending on how the app. is started, it might point somewhere very different to the directory of the application or data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String dataset = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/myFile.dat";
```

Comment: This is a fragile approach.  See my answer, as well as the thread linked by @talnicolas for more details.

Comment: -1 At first I did not notice the `/` before the file name.  That is even *more* fragile.  The `File(File, String)` constructor will account for different separators on different platforms.  For constructing `String` representations of file objects (something I do not recommend), use `System.getProperty("file.separator")`.