# NullPointerException when using a file as a input

Tags: java, maven, file-io, nullpointerexception

I was given a ready code sample for an assignemt but I can't get it to work. Love when this happens!

```
package kth.id2010.lab.lab04;


import edu.princeton.cs.introcs.In;
import java.net.URL;

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        URL url = Driver.class.getResource("kap1.txt");
        In input = new In(url);//this is where the nullPointer is pointing

        while(!input.isEmpty()){
            String line = input.readLine().trim();
            String[] words = line.split(" ");
            for (String word : words) {
                System.out.println(word);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the full exception that gets printed out.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> > at edu.princeton.cs.introcs.In.(In.java:105)
> >
> > at kth.id2010.lab.lab04.Driver.main(Driver.java:12)

I'm using maven

Comment: Do you have access to the source of In?

Comment: Can you use a debugger to check what the value of `url` is before the call to `new In(url);`?

Comment: Per the spec for Class.getResource -- `Returns: A URL object or null if no resource with this name is found`

Comment: The value of url is probably null. Check if the file kap1.txt exists in your classpath.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: @proko the file is located in the same package as the Driver class

Comment: Are you using Eclipse or another IDE?

Comment: I don't have experience developing in netBeans, but it probably points your working directory to outside your files next to your source folder. Try printing your current working path: 'System.getProperty("user.dir")'

Comment: @nmore okey it's pointing to where my src folder is located, so not to the actual folder where my files are and where the .txt file is located

Comment: @nmore I still can't get access to it, even if I move the file there, or if I change the `Driver.class.getResource` to contain all the folders between that one and the one my classes and .txt file are in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved when I put the .txt file in src/main/resources folder and changed
`Url url = Driver.Class.getResource("kap1.txt");`

to

`Url url = Driver.Class.getResource("/kap1.txt");`

don't know id this was what Sercan Ozdemir was refering to, but thought I should clarify how I solved it for coming users with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your path is wrong and `URL` object is null, please be sure the `kap1.txt` file is under your resources path and not in another folder, also try this:

```
URL url = Driver.class.getResource("/kap1.txt");
```

If you are not using resources then refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480398/java-reading-a-file-from-current-directory)

Comment: it is located in the same folder as Driver

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that your IDE does not necessarily point your current working directory to where your java files are located. Usually it points to just inside your project folder, but can use

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

to print out your actual working directory. The relative paths in your code will start from here, so you want to put your kap1.txt file in whatever directory is printed by the command above.

Comment: Ok I have not used get resource in this way before. It is not a standard way to read a file. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/best-way-to-read-a-text-file for more info on how to do this, though I'm not sure if you are allowed to change this code or not since you say it was given.

Comment: I'll look in to it, dont think its a problem It was more of a example code to get started