# FileNotFoundException but File present at right path

Tags: java, exception, filenotfoundexception

I'm new to programming, every time I try to read a file. I get FileNOtFoundException.

Where could I be going wrong?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadFile 
{
    public ReadFile()
    {
        readFile();
    }
    public void readFile()
    {
        String filename = "trees.txt";
        System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath()); //file is at this path.
        String name = "";
        try
        {
            FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(filename);
            Scanner parser = new Scanner(inputFile);
            while (parser.hasNextLine())
            {
                name = parser.nextLine();
                System.out.println(name);
            }
            inputFile.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException exception)
        {
            System.out.println(filename + " not found");
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any other way I could read the file?

Comment: Output the exception message and its stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

this code

```java
FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(filename);
```

You must define full path to file with name `filename` if not it will open file not at current working directory
you should try

```java
FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(new File(new File("."), filename));
// defind new File(".") it mean you will you open file in current working directory
```

you can read more at: [Java, reading a file from current directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480398/java-reading-a-file-from-current-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the path of the file you are actually trying to open so you can be sure that the file exists in the right location

```java
String filename = "trees.txt";
File file = new File(filename);
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Also, you are closing the `FileReader` inside the `try`, and not closing the `Scanner`, if some error ever occurs those resources will never be closed, you need to put those close statements in a `finally` block, or better use try with resources